# Scala match decomposition on infix operator

Tags: list, scala, match, infix-operator

I'm trying to understand the implementation of `List`s in Scala. In particular I'm trying to get my head around how you can write match expressions using an infix operator, for example:

```
a match {
  case Nil => "An empty list"
  case x :: Nil => "A list without a tail"
  case x :: xs => "A list with a tail"
}
```

How is the match expression allowed to be `x :: xs` rather than `List(x, xs)`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jay Conrad's answer is almost right.  The important thing is that *somewhere* there is an object named `::` which implements the `unapply` method, returning type `Option[(A, List[A])]`.  Thusly:

```
object :: {
  def unapply[A](ls: List[A]): Option[(A, A)] = {
    if (ls.empty) None
    else Some((ls.head, ls.tail))
  }
}

// case objects get unapply for free
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
```

In the case of `::` and `List`, this object happens to come out of the fact that `::` is a case class which extends the `List` trait.  However, as the above example shows, it doesn't *have* to be a case class at all.

Answer (score 7):

I believe [:: is actually a class](http://bit.ly/scala-api-scala-coloncolon) (which is a subclass of List), so saying `x :: xs` is mostly equivalent to `List(x, xs)`.

You can do this with other case classes that have operator names. For instance:

```
case class %%%(x: Int, y: Int)

a match {
  case x %%% y => x + y
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> How is the match expression allowed to be x :: xs rather than List(x, xs)?

To answer this question:

> When seen as a *pattern*, an infix
>   operation such as **p op q** is equivalent
>   to **op(p, q)**. That is, the infix
>   operator op is treated as a
>   *constructor pattern*.

(Programming in Scala, 1st ed., p. 331)

See also [scala case classes questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521011/scala-case-classes-questions)