# scala case classes questions

Tags: class, scala, case

I have two questions regarding the '::' case class.

:: can be used as

```
case head :: tail => ...
```

How does it work? Meaning, what is exactly the flow that Scala uses to match a List instance with the :: case class? Given that I have a class MyClass, with operator op, can I create a case class named op that I can use as:

```
case foo op bar => ....
```

?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059145/how-is-this-case-class-match-pattern-working, really.

Comment: my question was not just how come '::' is between the variables, but also how a case class can match instances of another class (the reason is that List#:: creates instances of :: case class)

Comment: The text cited by eed3si9n is on p. 331 in the PDF-edition of "Programming in Scala" (1st ed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
     scala> abstract class Stack {
     |     def push(n :Int):Stack
     | }
      defined class Stack

     scala> final case class push(st :Stack,hd :Int) extends Stack {
     |     override def push(n :Int):Stack = new push(this,n)
     | }
     defined class push

     scala> object NullStack extends Stack {
     |     override def push(n :Int):Stack = new push(null,n)
     | }
     defined module NullStack

     scala> val s = NullStack.push(1).push(2)
     s: Stack = push(push(null,1),2)

     scala> def test(s :Stack) = s match { case st push i => println(st +"push " + i) }
     test: (Stack)Unit

     scala> test(s)
     push(null,1)push 2
```

Comment: great answer! so the trick is that List#:: returns an instance of the case class ::.

Answer (score 3):

It's detailed in page 301 of [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala), About pattern matching on `List`s.

> The "cons" pattern `x :: xs` is a special case of an infix
>   operation pattern. You know already that, when seen as an expression,
>   an infix operation is equivalent to a method call. For patterns, the rules
>   are different: When seen as a pattern, an infix operation such as `p op q`
>   is equivalent to `op(p, q)`.
>   That is, the infix operator `op` is treated as a constructor pattern.
>   In particular, a cons pattern such as `x :: xs` is treated as `::(x, xs)`.
>   This hints that there should be a class named `::` that correspond to the pattern
>   constructor. Indeed there is such a class.
>   It is named `scala.::` and is exactly the class that builds non-empty lists.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the fact that :: is a case class is only half of the answer. The reason this works in pattern matching is that there is an *extractor* for object ::, which is generated automatically when a case class is defined. Conveniently, ::.unapply returns a List, because :: extends List. If you want to use the same trick for Lists, though, you won't be able to extend List, because it's *final*. What you can do is define an object with the appropriate unapply method, which has the expected return signature. For instance, to match the *last* element of a list, you can do:

```
object ::> {def unapply[A] (l: List[A]) = Some( (l.init, l.last) )}

List(1, 2, 3) match {
  case _ ::> last => println(last)
}

(1 to 9).toList match {
  case List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) ::> 9 => "woah!"
}
(1 to 9).toList match {
  case List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) ::> 8 ::> 9 => "w00t!"
}
```

The extractor must return an Option, which contains a tuple of the two deconstructed elements.

Comment: I don't think unapply applies here 
scala> val l = List(1, 2 , 3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
scala> scala.::.unapply(l)
<console>:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: ::[?]
val r = scala.::(1, Nil)
r: ::[Int] = List(1)

scala> scala.::.unapply(r)     
res7: Some[List[Int]] = Some(List())

so unapply works only if actually constructed by the case class, not for a general list.

Comment: There's nothing special about the unapply which a case class creates. Note that List is abstract and actually any non-empty list is an instance of scala.::

List(1).isInstanceOf[::[Int]]

Which means that what you're matching in patterns is actually instances of scala.:: (unless it's Nil). Notice also that as soon as you only redefine unapply for ::, pattern matching for Lists breaks:

object :: {def unapply = false}