# scala match case using :: for lists

Tags: scala

Given this pattern match:

```
List(1,2,3) match {
  case head :: tail => println(">>> head=" + head)
}
```

I'm assuming that '::' is the case class found in scala.collection.immutable, but how is '::' allowed to be written in that form (infix notation)? - is there a specific rule to allow for that?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to look at [Scala match decomposition on infix operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022218/scala-match-decomposition-on-infix-operator) and [How is this case class match pattern working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059145/how-is-this-case-class-match-pattern-working)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can even write:

```
val head :: tail = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Basically anything where a *pattern* is expected (an assignment, a `match` statement or a line in a for-comprehension) can take an *extractor*, which is defined as an entity with an `unapply` method.

One of the pieces of *syntactic sugar* that scala provides you with is that; if you have an extractor `X(a, b)`, this can be written as `a X b`. Here's an example with case classes (which have a default extractor):

```
scala> case class X(a: Int, b: String)
defined class X

scala> val a X b = X(1, "two")
a: Int = 1
b: String = two
```

The ability to write such entities *infix* extends to types as well:

```
scala> type MappedTo[A, B] = Map[A, B]
defined type alias MappedTo

scala> def foo(m: Int MappedTo String) = m foreach println
foo: (m: MappedTo[Int,String])Unit
```

Note that in neither case, does scala restrict such infix operators to symbolic identifiers

Answer (score 3):

Scala actually has an immutable class `::` which represents the non-empty list (the complement to `Nil`).  There's an infix notation for classes (which is also how things like `A <:< B` work) which is allowing you to write `head :: tail` instead of `::(head, tail)`.  Since `::` is a case class it has a default `unapply` which makes `case` work as you illustrate.