# Understand Scala match for case classes with two members

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I've been working with Scala for a while and it still troubles me a lot. I don't know why they made it so complex. I am trying to understand matching case classes when there are only two members for this case class

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    case class X(a: String, i: Int)
    def doSome(x: X): Unit = {
      x match {
        case "x" X 1 => print("ahhh") // <---- HERE ! 
        case X(_, _) => println("")
      }
    }

    doSome(X("x", 1))


    case class Y(a: String, i: Int, j: Int)

    def doAnother(y:Y): Unit = {
      y match {
        case "y" X 1 => print("ahhh") // how to make similar syntax when there are more than one syntax ?
        case Y(_, _,_) => println("")  // this is understandable
      }
    }
    doAnother(Y("y", 1,2))
  }
```

How can the syntax `"x" X 1` match `X("x",1)` and if `"x" X 1` can match match `X("x",1)` then what matches `Y("y",1,2)`, obviously `"y" Y 1 Y 2` doesn't work?

What is so special about the first argument if we can match on "y" Y (1,2)?

Comment: `case "y" Y (1,2) => ...`

Comment: @jwvh You can use more than 2 parameters with infix operators? How does the compiler know you want to give it 3 arguments and that you don't mean to give it a tuple? (`Y("y", (1, 2))`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala match decomposition on infix operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022218/scala-match-decomposition-on-infix-operator)

Answer (score 5):

At least in case of `List` it feels more natural to me, for example consider

```
List(42, 11) match {
  case head :: tail =>
  case Nil =>
  
}
```

as opposed to

```
List(42, 11) match {
  case ::(head, tail) =>
  case Nil =>
  
}
```

where `head :: tail` communicates directly the shape of the `List`.

As a side note, infix notation can sometimes communicate intent more clearly, for example, consider syntax of generalised constraints

```
implicitly[List[Int] <:< Iterable[Int]]    // infix type notation seems more natural
implicitly[<:<[List[Int], Iterable[Int]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use a language feature just because it is there.

In this case I can see no reason not to use the standard class matching version:

```
x match {
    case X("x", 1) => print("ahhh")
    case _ => println("")
  }
}

y match {
  case Y("y", 1, _) => print("ahhh")
  case _ => println("")
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't. But, tones of people are doing it and it is confusion, that is why I want to understand it. And what feature actually are you referring to?

Comment: I am referring to the `"x" X 1` syntax as synonym for `X("x", 1)`. I don't think I have ever seen that on StackOverflow before, and was not even aware it was an option.

Comment: Looking at the other answers I realise that I see it all the time but I simply didn't recognise it (e.g. in `case head :: tail =>`) which is really interesting. But I would still say it is a feature best avoided unless there is a strong use case.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the thing I was looking for is called "Infix Types". From [Scala for Impatient, 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134540565)

> An infix type is a type with two type parameters, written in “infix”
> syntax, with the type name between the type parameters. For example,
> you can write    String Map Int instead of    Map[String, Int] The
> infix notation is common in mathematics. For example, A × B = { (a, b)
> | a Œ A, b Œ B } is the set of pairs with components of types A and B.
> In Scala, this type is written as (A, B). If you prefer the
> mathematical notation, you can define type ×[A, B] = (A, B) Then you
> can write String × Int instead of (String, Int). All infix type
> operators have the same precedence. As with regular operators, they
> are left-associative unless their names end in :. For example,
> String × Int × Int means ((String, Int), Int). This type is similar
> to, but not the same, as (String, Int, Int), which could not be
> written in infix form in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your query on *What is so special about the first argument if we can match on "y" Y (1,2)?*: this is because of how your case class gets decomposed via its `unapply` method.

The preferred way of matching against a case class is how you've done in the second statement of both your methods.

However, for `Y`, the preferred way to match would be `case Y("y", 1, 2)` as mentioned in Tim's comment.

For `X`, a few ways you can use power of pattern matching are (similarly for `Y`):

```scala
case X("x", 1) => ???
case X(a, 1) => ???
case X(_, 1) => ???
case X("x", _) => ???
case x@X("x", _) => 
case X(a, b) if b > 5 => ???
```

The following, however, is a very bad style as it compromises readability and hence maintainability of the code

```scala
case "x" X 1 => print("ahhh")
```

As Mario mentioned, the way you're using pattern matching is more suited for lists instead of case classes, as it makes your code consistent with the way a list is structured (head cons tail), and thus enhances readability.

You can go through following articles for a more deeper understanding on how to exploit the power of scala's pattern matching:

- https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html
- https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html
- https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/match-expressions.html

Comment: Yes I agree but it is used by Scala Parser library like ^^ {case a~b => .... while ~ is a case class with two types.